# Make program beep on every exception raised

Tags: c#, exception, overriding, beep

How can I make my console program or service to:

- `Console.Beep()` on every single exception?
- beep on specific exceptions?

Edit 1: As I am working on legacy code which contains hundreds of exceptions already, adding `Console.Beep()` in every single of them is not an option and on top of that it's also not easily maintainable, taking into consideration the plethora of the existing exceptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, simply you can put the code you expect to throw an exception in a try catch block like this:

```
try
{
     // your code here
}
catch (Exception) // this goes to every single exception, if you want to beep on a specific one just replace the Exception with the exception you expect e.g NullReferenceException
{
     Console.Beep();
     throw;
}
```

If you do not want to see the exception when it occurs, just remove the throw statement from the catch block.

Comment: So, you are looking for something like for example an event which is being executed when an exception is thrown?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.firstchanceexception(v=vs.110).aspx

If so, there is an example of one. You implement what you want to be executed when an exception is thrown, in your case a console.beep

Comment: How about the cases when an exception is unhandled?

Comment: Well, I think even when it is the exception is unhandled the event still executes.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know when an exception is *thrown* (as opposed to when it is uncaught), it looks like you can use the [AppDomain.FirstChanceException event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997368%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to register for notification right at the point where an exception is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Console.Beep()` inside a try catch block. Or, if you want the beep sound for specific exception, use it only when the exception you want has been thrown.

```
try
{
    // Your code that is likely to throw exception.
}
catch (InvalidCastException e)
{
    // Beep when invalid cast.
    Console.Beep();
}
catch (NullReferenceException e)
{
    // Don't beep on the null reference. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Beep on every single exception:

```
try
{
    //...
}
catch
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```

Beep on specific exception:

```
try
{

}
catch(InvalidOperationException ex)
{
    Console.Beep();
}
```